# Identify the radius of convergence from ordinary generating function

Tags: convergence-divergence, generating-functions

Assume we have the ordinary generating function $f(x)$ of a series:

$f(x) = \tan x$

Can we identify the radius of convergence for this series?

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint}$: The  generating  function  of  a  sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is defined as:   $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_nx^n$.

$\bf{Additional}$

[image]

Comment: So how can I expand a GF like $\tan x$ to get the coefficient(which equals to $f_n$) ?

Comment: @cinvro, like you always do. Yes, $\tan x$ is special, it hasn't got a "nice" expression for the coefficients (like, say, $\exp(x)$ or $\cos x$).

Comment: Let $y = f(x) = tan (x)$. 

$f(x) = tan (x); f(0) = 0 $

$f '(x) = sec² x = 1 + tan² (x) = 1 + y²; f '(0) = 1 $

$f ''(x) = 2yy'; f ''(0) = 0 $

$f '''(x) = 2yy'' + 2(y')²; f ''' (x) = 2 $

. 
. 
. 
. 
.

Comment: I noticed that there are singularities for $tan x$, such as $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,..., are these intervals indicates the radius of convergence?

Comment: You have it almost. Convince yourself now that radius of convergence is $|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ i.e, $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit, I think this is something I didn't get during the lecture.

Comment: Idea: You singularities are where your function blow up, so your iteration cannot converge, so as long as you are never near them you are fine. Look at the new edit.